# SQL Query problem

Tags: sql, database

Consider two tables. Technician table has fields like T_ID,T_Name. Project table has fields like P_ID,P_Name, P_Date.

Now, since a Technician can work on many projects and a project can be done by many Technicians. Therefore, as evident, there is a many to many relationship between the two tables. Break the many to many, and create a new table called Assignment which consists of the foreign keys T_ID and P_ID.

Here is the question: I want to find out a list of who a particular technician (Technician with T_ID = 1 worked with over the last month (April/2011). For example if Technician 1 worked with Tech 2 and 3 then they qualify for the above query result and i would like tech 2 and Tech 3 T_ID T_name.

The answer can be also based on two queries linked.
Kindly let me know what will be the query for the mentioned problem.

Comment: I added the homework tag for you. You should post what you've tried so far, and explain how it didn't work the way you thought it would We can then help you figure out how to solve it, so you'll actually learn something in the process.

Answer (score 1):

This would find all the people who worked on assignments with the technician who has ID = 10.  Maybe:

```
SELECT t.T_ID, t.T_Name
FROM Technician t, Project p, Assignments a
WHERE t.T_ID = a.T_ID and p.P_ID = a.P_ID
and a.P_ID IN (SELECT assign.P_ID FROM Assignments assign, Projects proj WHERE assign.T_ID = 10 and assign.P_ID = proj.P_ID and (proj.P_Date - getdate() <= 30))
```

The date is a little bit of a guess as I'm not sure on the syntax, however the rest should get the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Give Assignment table a primary key of its own (because composite keys suck).
The two ? characters represent the ID of the Technician that you're asking 
who worked with.  For example:  "Who worked with Technician 5", the ? would be
5's.

```
SELECT 
    a1.T_ID
FROM 
    Assignment a1
WHERE 
    a1.A_ID IN ( 
        SELECT assignment.A_ID
        FROM Assignment a2
        WHERE a2.T_ID = ?
    ) 
    AND a1.T_ID != ?
;
```

Comment: Please don't complete homework assignments; the phrasing of the question itself identifies it as such. If you do, the asker doesn't learn anything, and we end up trying to fix or maintain what they can't do in the future.

Comment: I like homework. And writing it helps me. It's fun. My answer probably needs to be tweaked anyways. At least he can see some logic in formatting an answer. Also, I'll be able to get feedback on whether other people think composite keys suck. Maybe he's just stuck and doesn't know where to start.